# dump command is showing empty brackets in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When I used the following command in the grunt shell:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE(category);
dump B;
```

The output was:

```
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
```

and so on.

`Category` is the string(char array) which I want to display using dump.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "DESCRIBE B" to the end of the script.

The output appears to be 7 nulls, instead of an expected chararray or string.  The DESCRIBE command will either verify that category is actually a string equal to "() () () () () () ()" or is using an unexpected schema.